# Does the text of the 13th Century Vita of St. Dymphna still exist today?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, saint

The 1913 *Catholic Encyclopedia* [says the following](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05221b.htm) about St. Dymphna:

> The earliest historical account of the veneration of St. Dymphna dates from the middle of the thirteenth century. Under Bishop Guy I of Cambrai (1238-47), Pierre, a canon of the church of Saint Aubert at Cambrai, wrote a "Vita" of the saint, from which we learn that she had been venerated for many years in a church at Gheel (province of Antwerp, Belgium), which was devoted to her. The author expressly states that he has drawn his biography from oral tradition.

Does the text of this Vita still exist today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Acta Sanctorum* is an official collection of saints' lives by various authors used for their processes of beatification or canonization.

St. Dympna's *vita* is [pp. 475-495 of *Acta Sanctorum* vol. 16](https://archive.org/details/actasanctorum16unse/page/n576); p. 476 says the author is the [canon regular](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32306) Peter of St. Aubert [of Cambrai](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/dcamb.html) ([*Cameracensis*](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/dcamb.html)):

> *Vitam* S. Dympnæ *scripsit* Petrus Canonicus Regularis S. Autberti Cameracensis

---

Also, according to [Fr. Butler's biography of her](https://www.bartleby.com/210/5/152.html), this is another *vita* of her:

> Molanus, Miræus, the Roman Martyrology, Henschenius, t. 3, Maij. p. 477